# Can I turn an existing ax object into a 3d projection?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created some axes using `plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2)`.  I would like to make `ax[1,1]` a 3d axis so I can make a plot like [this](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.bar).

Is there anyway I can turn an existing ax object into a 3d ax?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, because a 3D axis is a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.Axes3DSubplot` object, while a regular axis is a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` object.

So, its not just the case of changing one property of an existing object, since its a completely different object that gets created when you `add_subplot(projection='3d')`.

I think you would have to explicitly create your subplots, something like:

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax3=fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax4=fig.add_subplot(2,2,4,projection='3d')
```

Or, alternatively, remove the 2D axis and add it back in as a 3D axis:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2)
ax[1,1].remove()
ax[1,1]=fig.add_subplot(2,2,4,projection='3d')
```