# Colorbar labels are not appearing when plotted in subplots as cartopy projections

Tags: python, matplotlib, projection, colorbar, cartopy

The colorbar appears nicely, but no values come with it. See the code below.

The code plots 2 columns, each with 4 rows for the maps and an additional row for the colorbars. The labels on the colorbars don't appear, and I don't know why.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LatitudeFormatter, LongitudeFormatter

# for labeling lat and lon
lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True)
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()

# lon and lat
lon = np.linspace(-180,180,360)
lat = np.linspace(0,90,90)

# initate figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(5,2,subplot_kw={'projection':  ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)}, \
                       gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [0.33,0.33,0.33,0.33,0.05],'width_ratios': [1, 1], 'wspace': 0.1, 'hspace': 0.1},figsize=[15,10])

# mundhenk plotting
for i in range(0,4):

    # create map
    referenced_data = 20.0 * np.random.rand(90,360)
    im1 = ax[i,0].contourf(lon,lat,referenced_data,cmap='Blues',levels=np.linspace(0,20,6),extend='max')
    ax[i,0].coastlines()
    ax[i,0].set_xticks([0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax[i,0].set_yticks([0, 20, 40, 60, 80], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    if i < 3:
        ax[i,0].set_xticklabels([])
        ax[i,0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
    else:
        ax[i,0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
        ax[i,0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
    ax[i,0].set_ylim(20,80)
    ax[i,0].set_xlim(-100,150)

# Add a colorbar for all subplots
cbar1 = plt.colorbar(im1, cax=ax[4,0], orientation='horizontal', label='(AR Day) / day')
cbar1.ax.set_aspect(0.075)

# tempestextreme plotting
for i in range(0,4):

    # create map
    referenced_data = 20.0 * np.random.rand(90,360)
    im2 = ax[i,1].contourf(lon,lat,referenced_data,cmap='Blues',levels=np.linspace(0,20,6),extend='max')
    ax[i,1].coastlines()
    ax[i,1].set_xticks([0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax[i,1].set_yticks([0, 20, 40, 60, 80], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    if i < 3:
        ax[i,1].set_xticklabels([])
    else:
        ax[i,1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
    ax[i,1].set_yticklabels([])
    ax[i,1].set_ylim(20,80)
    ax[i,1].set_xlim(-100,150)

cbar2 = plt.colorbar(im2,cax=ax[4,1],orientation='horizontal')
cbar2.ax.set_aspect(0.075)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `ax[4, 0]` and `ax[4, 1]` are specified as `ccrs.PlateCarree` projections, which is causing the colorbar to display incorrectly.

  - Similar to [How to combine 3d projections with 2d subplots and set the width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76239866/7758804), certain objects may not work with a projection, but it's possible to combine different projections, or None, in subplots.
- The easiest option seems to be:

  1. Create the subplots as you are doing with `gridspec`, so a position will be allocated for the colorbars.
  2. Remove the two `Axes` allocated for the colorbars.
  3. Add new subplots, in the same position, that aren't projections.

  - It's easiest because it doesn't require changing the existing loops.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LatitudeFormatter, LongitudeFormatter

# for labeling lat and lon
lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True)
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()

# lon and lat
lon = np.linspace(-180, 180, 360)
lat = np.linspace(0, 90, 90)

# initate figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(5, 2, subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)},
                       gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.05],
                                    'width_ratios': [1, 1],
                                    'wspace': 0.1, 'hspace': 0.1},
                       figsize=[15, 10])

# remove the Axes with a projection
ax[4, 0].remove()
ax[4, 1].remove()

# add new subplots that aren't projections
ax9 = fig.add_subplot(5, 2, 9)
ax10 = fig.add_subplot(5, 2, 10)

# mundhenk plotting
for i in range(0, 4):

    # create map
    referenced_data = 20.0 * np.random.rand(90,360)
    im1 = ax[i,0].contourf(lon,lat,referenced_data,cmap='Blues',levels=np.linspace(0,20,6),extend='max')
    ax[i,0].coastlines()
    ax[i,0].set_xticks([0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax[i,0].set_yticks([0, 20, 40, 60, 80], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    if i < 3:
        ax[i,0].set_xticklabels([])
        ax[i,0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
    else:
        ax[i,0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
        ax[i,0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
    ax[i,0].set_ylim(20,80)
    ax[i,0].set_xlim(-100,150)

# Add a colorbar for all subplots
cbar1 = fig.colorbar(im1, cax=ax9, orientation='horizontal', label='(AR Day) / day')
cbar1.ax.set_aspect(0.075)

# tempestextreme plotting
for i in range(0, 4):

    # create map
    referenced_data = 20.0 * np.random.rand(90,360)
    im2 = ax[i,1].contourf(lon,lat,referenced_data,cmap='Blues',levels=np.linspace(0,20,6),extend='max')
    ax[i,1].coastlines()
    ax[i,1].set_xticks([0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax[i,1].set_yticks([0, 20, 40, 60, 80], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    if i < 3:
        ax[i,1].set_xticklabels([])
    else:
        ax[i,1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
    ax[i,1].set_yticklabels([])
    ax[i,1].set_ylim(20,80)
    ax[i,1].set_xlim(-100,150)

cbar2 = fig.colorbar(im2, cax=ax10, orientation='horizontal')
cbar2.ax.set_aspect(0.075)
```

[image]

---

- As pointed out by [RuthC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501128/ruthc), [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic.html) may be used to create [per-Axes subplot keyword arguments](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/mosaic.html#per-axes-subplot-keyword-arguments).

  - Note the differences in:

    1. Creating the `Axes` object
    2. How the `Axes` objects are referenced, and iterated through

```py
# for labeling lat and lon
lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True)
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()

# lon and lat
lon = np.linspace(-180, 180, 360)
lat = np.linspace(0, 90, 90)

# create subplot mosaic with different keyword arguments
fig, ax = plt.subplot_mosaic("AB;CD;EF;GH;IJ",
                             per_subplot_kw={('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'): {'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)}},
                             gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.05],
                                          'width_ratios': [1, 1],
                                          'wspace': 0.1, 'hspace': 0.1},
                             figsize=[15, 10])

# mundhenk plotting; iterate through the left Axes letters
for v, i in enumerate(['A', 'C', 'E', 'G']):

    # create map
    referenced_data = 20.0 * np.random.rand(90,360)
    im1 = ax[i].contourf(lon,lat,referenced_data,cmap='Blues',levels=np.linspace(0,20,6),extend='max')
    ax[i].coastlines()
    ax[i].set_xticks([0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax[i].set_yticks([0, 20, 40, 60, 80], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    if v < 3:
        ax[i].set_xticklabels([])
        ax[i].yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
    else:
        ax[i].xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
        ax[i].yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
    ax[i].set_ylim(20,80)
    ax[i].set_xlim(-100,150)

# Add a colorbar for all subplots
cbar1 = fig.colorbar(im1, cax=ax['I'], orientation='horizontal', label='(AR Day) / day')
cbar1.ax.set_aspect(0.075)

# tempestextreme plotting; iterate through the right Axes letters
for v, i in enumerate(['B', 'D', 'F', 'H']):

    # create map
    referenced_data = 20.0 * np.random.rand(90,360)
    im2 = ax[i].contourf(lon,lat,referenced_data,cmap='Blues',levels=np.linspace(0,20,6),extend='max')
    ax[i].coastlines()
    ax[i].set_xticks([0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax[i].set_yticks([0, 20, 40, 60, 80], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    if v < 3:
        ax[i].set_xticklabels([])
    else:
        ax[i].xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
    ax[i].set_yticklabels([])
    ax[i].set_ylim(20,80)
    ax[i].set_xlim(-100,150)

cbar2 = fig.colorbar(im2, cax=ax['J'], orientation='horizontal')
cbar2.ax.set_aspect(0.075)
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is useful in that it shows two work arounds to get this to work, but its even easier if you just let the colorbars make their own axes rather than trying to make the axes part of a gridspec directly.  You do this simply by specifying `ax=ax[:, 0]` in the call to `colorbar`.

Note that you can also get rid of the awkward labelling of ticks using `label_outer`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# lon and lat
lon = np.linspace(-180, 180, 360)
lat = np.linspace(0, 90, 90)

# initate figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, 2, subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)},
                       figsize=[15, 10], layout='compressed')


for i in range(0, 4):
    referenced_data = 20.0 * np.random.rand(90,360)
    im1 = ax[i,0].contourf(lon,lat,referenced_data,cmap='Blues',levels=np.linspace(0,20,6),extend='max')
    ax[i,0].set_ylim(20, 80)
    ax[i,0].set_xlim(-100, 150)
    ax[i,0].set_xticks([0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax[i,0].set_yticks([0, 20, 40, 60, 80], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# Add a colorbar for all subplots in first column
cbar1 = fig.colorbar(im1, ax=ax[:, 0], orientation='horizontal', shrink=0.6, label='(AR Day) / day')

for i in range(0, 4):
    # create map
    referenced_data = 40.0 * np.random.rand(90,360)
    im2 = ax[i,1].contourf(lon,lat,referenced_data,cmap='Blues',levels=np.linspace(0,40,12),extend='max')
    ax[i,1].set_ylim(20, 80)
    ax[i,1].set_xlim(-100, 150)
    ax[i,1].set_xticks([0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax[i,1].set_yticks([0, 20, 40, 60, 80], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# remove inner tick labels:
for axx in ax.flat:
    axx.label_outer()

# Add a colorbar for all subplots in second column
cbar2 = fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax[:, 1], orientation='horizontal', shrink=0.6)
```

[image]

Comment: I notice you lost the map here. Any idea why?

Comment: It wasn’t necessary to answer the question.

Comment: Well, yes. One solution is to remove cartopy altogether. Sorry for not specifying that having maps in the plots was a necessity!

Comment: @Joe this is still a map, I trimmed the `ax.coastlines` call, but if you add it, this works exactly the same.